# Django REST get "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and return "application/xml"

Tags: python, django, xml, django-rest-framework

I'm writing integration with payments gateway and I have problem with sending response to provider.
They are sending request with data in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" form and are expection. Thats their request headers:

```
{'Content-Length': '917', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept': 'application/xml', 'User-Agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.15)', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate', 'Host': '89.xxxxxxxx', 'Via': '1.1 payxxxxxx (squid/3.5.20)', 'X-Forwarded-For': '10.xxxxxx', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=259200', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

I don't know how to use two renderer classes in django - one for taking request and one for responding. I was trying to add

```
parser_classes = (XMLParser,)
```

but then it shows me error **415** as response (Unsupported Media Type).

Rn I'm getting **406**  - (Not Acceptable) - *{"detail":"Could not satisfy the request Accept header."}*

Payment gateway is sending POST request. My attempt for handling it was:

```
class ITNView(APIView):
    #parser_classes = (XMLParser, JSONParser)

def post(self, request):
    body = request.data['transaction'] #form-encoded
    print(body)
    print(request.headers)
    return Response(request.data, content_type="application/xml")
```

but this doesn't work.

Have you an idea how can I handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded as request data and respond with XML?

Answer (score 0):

@xGoldeNx what you want is the FormParser. To see the document in the Django Rest Framework page: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#formparser

Basically

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser

class ITNView(APIView):
   parser_classes = [FormParser]
```

In that way the data will be in request.data as you expect.